# Can i use Node.js in my Asp.net Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, webrtc

I have a Asp.net Application (forms). I want to add video chat feature using webrtc! this video chat application is working on node.js! how can i integrate this webrtc app to my asp.net application ?

Comment: See if this link help.https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

Comment: @Chandu do i need to change anything to make it work using iisnode?
I've installed iisnode and manged to run the samples it comes with (the WWW folder) but haven't been able to run the webrtc sample code! should i reconfigure anything ?

Comment: YOu might find it simpler not to.  Consider decoupling your functions and having the node app be separate from your ASP.Net app; you can run it under a subdomain of your .net app to avoid same-origin restrictions.  Keeps things cleaner and more scalable too.

Answer (score 1):

Try [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), a realtime HTTP streaming (comet) server built for Microsoft stack (.net/iis) using the [Bayeus protocol](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html). Search "websync" part in [this comment](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/56#issuecomment-20090650), for "just" an example!

You just need to [download](http://www.frozenmountain.com/signin?redirect=/downloads#websync) their samples; try a simple text-chat sample; and use it for signaling. Simple!

**Note:** Usually WebRTC developers use node.js for signaling purpose only; however a few people use it to keep sessions to detect presence of the users; if the app you referenced is using such kind of things; then WebSync is not easier because you've to change a lot many things on the server end. Then I'll suggest you try something like [this](https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp). And obviously [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)!